Changing values in a dataframe under growth change with year condition
Suppose I have
sample = {"Location+Type": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
         "Year": ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"],
         "Price": [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=sample)
df_sample['pct_pop'] = df_sample['Price'].pct_change()
df_sample.head(8)

From say 2012, I want to make a change in the dataframes values following the pct_chage() values. In other words, if the percentage change is greater than 30 percent than I want to average the previous values with respect to the Location+Type column starting from the year of 2012.
Thus the new dataframe would look like this
sample = {"Location+Type": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
         "Year": ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"],
         "Price": [1, 2, 1.5, 1.33, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=sample)
df_sample['pct_pop'] = df_sample['Price'].pct_change()
df_sample.head(8)

Still having some issues following the answers for my particular data which is instead of changing from 2012 its 2023, here is the shared drive https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/11dh05Dq_VNfUNgALeMg7MI1keVQdN0ZN
And here is the code modified
df_complete['Year'] = df_complete['Year'].astype(int) #  just in case if "Year" holds strings

def calculate_new_price(row, df):
    current_index = row.name  # row number will be used to check if value is in the first of the DF
    # Check if row is not the first
    if current_index > 0:
        # assign previous pct_pop value to variable: previous_pct_pop
        previous_pct_pop = df.loc[current_index - 1, 'pct_pop']
        # Check if the year is 2023 or later and if the difference in pct_pop is 0.3 or more
        if row['Year'] >= 2023 and abs(row['pct_pop'] - previous_pct_pop) >= 0.3:
            # Filter previous years
            previous_data = df[(df['Year'] < row['Year']) & (df['Location+Type'] == row['Location+Type'])]
            # Calculate average if row above is not empty
            if not previous_data.empty:
                return previous_data['Median_Home_Value_prediction'].mean()
        else:
            return row['Median_Home_Value_prediction']  # if pct_pop change was smaller than 0.3 or year is older than 2012, - use default price.
    else:
        return row['Median_Home_Value_prediction']   # if index 0 (first row) use value from first row of col: Price
    return None

# Apply the function to create the new_price column
df_complete['Median_Home_Value_prediction_new'] = df_complete.apply(lambda row: calculate_new_price(row, df_complete), axis=1)


maybe you should use rolling window to have access to previous row. OR use .shift() to create new column with data moved to previous row - and this way you have all data in one row.

can you double check your output "price" results?
it looks like it should be 1,2,1.5, 1.33 ,1,1,1,1 - if I understood you correctly.
1.33 is based on initial data [1, 2, 1]/3 .
Looks like you adjusting new price based on new price...
1.5 = [1, 2, 1.5]/3

@NoobVB Corrected it sorry about that

Pandas Style
We have 4 steps here that can be done using typical pandas tools:

Sort data.
Find where the percent change exceeds the limit.
Calculate cumulative means.
Replace the data with average values by masking.

# Load data and define key variables
data = pd.DataFrame({
     'Location+Type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
     'Year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013],
     'Price': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
})
group = 'Location+Type'
inner_index = 'Year'
value = 'Price'
index_start = 2012                   # apply to index >= this one
value_pct_change_upper_limit = 0.3   # update values where percent change >= this one

# Sort and group data
df = data.sort_values([group, inner_index])
by_groups = df.groupby(group, as_index=False)

# Find where abs(percent change) is greater than or equal to change limit
pct_change_ge_limit = (by_groups[value].pct_change()
                       .abs().ge(value_pct_change_upper_limit)
                       .rename('pct_change'))

# Find cumulative mean by groups shifted one step forward
# to the place where they can be used
cum_mean = (by_groups[value].expanding().mean()
            .groupby(level=0).shift().bfill()  # shift the means to replace the values following them
            .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)   # drop group names returend at the level 0
            .rename('cum_mean'))

# Replace values with cumulative means
# where inner group index (Year) starts from a given value
# and abs(percent change) >= percent change limit
df[value] = df[value].mask(
    df[inner_index].ge(index_start) & pct_change_ge_limit, 
    other=cum_mean
)

NumPy/Numba Acceleration
To make it faster, we can calculate whatever is needed on the fly with help of NumPy and Numba with some modifications in the algorithm:

Sort data by group (e.g. Location+Type)  and inner group index (e.g. Year).
Find group start/end points.
Iterate over every group starting from the end until the group index limit.
Calculate the average only if needed.

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


def get_bounds(series):
    '''Return the starting points of consecutive values
    and put `len(series)` at the end,
    where `series` is a properly sorted `pandas.Series`
    '''
    grouper = series.ne(series.shift()) 
    size = grouper.sum() + 1
    bounds = np.empty(size, dtype=int)
    bounds[:-1] = np.nonzero(grouper)[0]
    bounds[-1] = len(series)
    return bounds


@njit
def modify_excessive_values(bounds, years, values, year_limit, pct_limit):
    '''Replace the values with averages of their predecessors
    if their percent change exceeds pct_limit 
    and the corresponding year is more or equal the year_limit
    '''
    out = values.copy().astype('float')     # use float to avoid truncating means for integer values
    for left, right in zip(bounds[:-1], bounds[1:]):     # iterate over groups
        ind = right - 1      
        while years[ind] >= year_limit and ind > left:   # iterate inside the group starting from its end
            if abs(out[ind]/out[ind-1] - 1) >= pct_limit:
                out[ind] = out[left:ind].mean()
            ind -= 1
    return out

Working with the original data
Here's an example of the original data:
csv_data = '''\
Location+Type,Year,Tract_number,Median_Home_Value_prediction,pct_pop
"Census Tract 1.02, Jefferson County, Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2015,5069000102,112000,0.3365155131264916
"Census Tract 1.02, Jefferson County, Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2016,5069000102,117811,0.0518839285714285
"Census Tract 1.02, Jefferson County, Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2017,5069000102,122031,0.0358200847119538
"Census Tract 1.02, Jefferson County, Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2018,5069000102,127031,0.0409731953356113
"Census Tract 1.02, Jefferson County, Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2019,5069000102,132779,0.045248797537609
"Census Tract 1.02, Jefferson County, Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2020,5069000102,145703,0.0973346688858931
"Census Tract 1.02, Jefferson County, Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2021,5069000102,166769,0.1445817862363849
"Census Tract 1.02; Jefferson County; Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2023,5069000102,168596,0.594531611608196
"Census Tract 1.02; Jefferson County; Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2024,5069000102,213385,0.2656597148863364
"Census Tract 1.02; Jefferson County; Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2025,5069000102,176771,-0.1715863204676784
"Census Tract 1.02; Jefferson County; Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2026,5069000102,181905,0.0290384486578858
"Census Tract 1.02; Jefferson County; Arkansas: Summary level: 140, state:05> county:069> tract:000102",2027,5069000102,291646,0.6032906623467567

"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2010,18003003400,86600,-0.7280150753768844
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2011,18003003400,85500,-0.0127020785219399
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2012,18003003400,85900,0.0046783625730995
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2013,18003003400,85400,-0.0058207217694994
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2014,18003003400,83900,-0.0175644028103044
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2015,18003003400,83200,-0.0083432657926102
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2016,18003003400,87700,0.0540865384615385
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2017,18003003400,90800,0.0353477765108323
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2018,18003003400,100400,0.1057268722466959
"Census Tract 34.00, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2019,18003003400,103100,0.0268924302788844
"Census Tract 34, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2020,18003003400,111500,-0.3719003776540518
"Census Tract 34, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2021,18003003400,117700,0.0556053811659191
"Census Tract 34, Allen County, Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2022,18003003400,132200,0.1231945624468988
"Census Tract 34; Allen County; Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2023,18003003400,186965,-0.4049759667529261
"Census Tract 34; Allen County; Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2024,18003003400,209587,0.1209947984468349
"Census Tract 34; Allen County; Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2025,18003003400,186934,-0.1080818221957703
"Census Tract 34; Allen County; Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2026,18003003400,194739,0.0417513977349723
"Census Tract 34; Allen County; Indiana: Summary level: 140, state:18> county:003> tract:003400",2027,18003003400,200658,0.0303972448096778

"Census Tract 34, Genesee County, Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2010,26049003400,113600,-0.2685125563425627
"Census Tract 34, Genesee County, Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2011,26049003400,173800,0.5299295774647887
"Census Tract 34, Genesee County, Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2012,26049003400,164000,-0.0563866513233601
"Census Tract 34, Genesee County, Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2013,26049003400,115300,-0.2969512195121951
"Census Tract 34, Genesee County, Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2014,26049003400,50000,-0.5663486556808326
"Census Tract 34, Genesee County, Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2016,26049003400,13900,-0.722
"Census Tract 34, Genesee County, Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2022,26049003400,9999,-0.2806474820143885
"Census Tract 34; Genesee County; Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2023,26049003400,64772,-0.5894961662501869
"Census Tract 34; Genesee County; Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2025,26049003400,89406,0.3803308197295025
"Census Tract 34; Genesee County; Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2026,26049003400,61398,-0.3132673555695764
"Census Tract 34; Genesee County; Michigan: Summary level: 140, state:26> county:049> tract:003400",2027,26049003400,37238,-0.3935019397012603

"Census Tract 113.02, Jefferson County, Texas: Summary level: 140, state:48> county:245> tract:011302",2018,48245011302,154081,0.4454127579737335
"Census Tract 113.02, Jefferson County, Texas: Summary level: 140, state:48> county:245> tract:011302",2019,48245011302,160861,0.0440028296804926
'''

There you can find all the records for 4 selected Tract_number values representing some oddities of data:

Location+Type can have up to 3 variants for one Tract_number, which complicate grouping data by them. Especially note the difference in the use of commas and semicolons, which can be difficult to pick out visually. So maybe it's better to use Tract_number for grouping, not Location+Type.
There are missing years in the middle, making pct_change difficult to interpret (e.g. missing 2022 where Tract_number is 5069000102).
Far not all years are represented for Tract_number, sometimes there are only 2 records in a group.
The minimum year found is 2010. However, the initial year in the group may be different from 2010, which may complicate the interpretation of the mean values.
All of the above oddities are not rare exceptions, but are widely represented in the data (e.g. 7% of all Tract_number have missing years in the middle).

Anyway, let's do the calculations on the data example with 2020 as a starting year and grouping the data by Tract_number:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Load data and define key variables
file = StringIO(csv_data)
df = pd.read_csv(file)
group = 'Tract_number'
inner_index = 'Year'
value = 'Median_Home_Value_prediction'
index_start = 2020               # inner_index >= index_start
pct_change_upper_limit = 0.3     # pct_change >= pct_change_upper_limit

# Modify data
df.sort_values([group, inner_index], inplace=True)
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby(group)[value].pct_change()
df[f'New_{value}'] = modify_excessive_values(
    get_bounds(df[group]), 
    df[inner_index].values,
    df[value].values,
    index_start,
    pct_change_upper_limit
)
result = df[[group, inner_index, value, f'New_{value}', 'pct_change']]
result.columns = ['Tract', 'Year', 'Value', 'New_Value', 'pct_change']

>>> print(result)
          Tract  Year   Value      New_Value  pct_change
0    5069000102  2015  112000  112000.000000         NaN
1    5069000102  2016  117811  117811.000000    0.051884
2    5069000102  2017  122031  122031.000000    0.035820
3    5069000102  2018  127031  127031.000000    0.040973
4    5069000102  2019  132779  132779.000000    0.045249
5    5069000102  2020  145703  145703.000000    0.097335
6    5069000102  2021  166769  166769.000000    0.144582
7    5069000102  2023  168596  168596.000000    0.010955
8    5069000102  2024  213385  213385.000000    0.265659
9    5069000102  2025  176771  176771.000000   -0.171587
10   5069000102  2026  181905  181905.000000    0.029043
11   5069000102  2027  291646  151343.727273    0.603287
12  18003003400  2010   86600   86600.000000         NaN
13  18003003400  2011   85500   85500.000000   -0.012702
14  18003003400  2012   85900   85900.000000    0.004678
15  18003003400  2013   85400   85400.000000   -0.005821
16  18003003400  2014   83900   83900.000000   -0.017564
17  18003003400  2015   83200   83200.000000   -0.008343
18  18003003400  2016   87700   87700.000000    0.054087
19  18003003400  2017   90800   90800.000000    0.035348
20  18003003400  2018  100400  100400.000000    0.105727
21  18003003400  2019  103100  103100.000000    0.026892
22  18003003400  2020  111500  111500.000000    0.081474
23  18003003400  2021  117700  117700.000000    0.055605
24  18003003400  2022  132200  132200.000000    0.123195
25  18003003400  2023  186965   96453.846154    0.414259
26  18003003400  2024  209587  209587.000000    0.120996
27  18003003400  2025  186934  186934.000000   -0.108084
28  18003003400  2026  194739  194739.000000    0.041753
29  18003003400  2027  200658  200658.000000    0.030395
30  26049003400  2010  113600  113600.000000         NaN
31  26049003400  2011  173800  173800.000000    0.529930
32  26049003400  2012  164000  164000.000000   -0.056387
33  26049003400  2013  115300  115300.000000   -0.296951
34  26049003400  2014   50000   50000.000000   -0.566349
35  26049003400  2016   13900   13900.000000   -0.722000
36  26049003400  2022    9999    9999.000000   -0.280647
37  26049003400  2023   64772   91514.142857    5.477848
38  26049003400  2025   89406   88171.375000    0.380319
39  26049003400  2026   61398   88308.555556   -0.313268
40  26049003400  2027   37238   85617.500000   -0.393498
41  48245011302  2018  154081  154081.000000         NaN
42  48245011302  2019  160861  160861.000000    0.044003


You can achieve this this way:
import pandas as pd

sample = {
    "Location+Type": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Year": ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"],
    "Price": [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=sample)
df_sample['pct_pop'] = df_sample['Price'].pct_change()

def update_prices_corrected(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, 'Year'] >= '2012' and df.loc[i, 'pct_pop'] > 0.3:
            prev_prices = df[(df['Location+Type'] == df.loc[i, 'Location+Type']) & (df['Year'] < df.loc[i, 'Year'])]['Price']
            avg_price = prev_prices.mean()
            df.at[i, 'Price'] = avg_price
    df['pct_pop'] = df['Price'].pct_change()
    return df

df_sample_corrected = update_prices_corrected(df_sample.copy())

print(df_sample_corrected)

which gives
  Location+Type  Year     Price   pct_pop
0             A  2010  1.000000       NaN
1             A  2011  2.000000  1.000000
2             A  2012  1.000000 -0.500000
3             A  2013  1.333333  0.333333
4             B  2010  1.000000 -0.250000
5             B  2011  1.000000  0.000000
6             B  2012  1.000000  0.000000
7             B  2013  1.000000  0.000000


If we are starting from 2012 should row 2 to be 1.5?

I believe row 2 needs be 1.5 and row 3 remains to be 1.333, any idea how to correct the code?

quite similar approach as previous one,
it creates "new_price" column with the new vals as requested.
(+- 0.3 pct_pop change and year 2012 or later)
Sadly, it also iterates each row and can become slow for larger amounts of data...
And instead of .shift, code simply checks row above using index...
I am learning also, - would be nice to see a vectorized approach also.
df_sample['Year'] = df_sample['Year'].astype(int) #  just in case if "Year" holds strings

def calculate_new_price(row, df):
    current_index = row.name  # row number will be used to check if value is in the first of the DF
    # Check if row is not the first
    if current_index > 0:
        # assign previous pct_pop value to variable: previous_pct_pop
        previous_pct_pop = df.loc[current_index - 1, 'pct_pop']
        # Check if the year is 2012 or later and if the difference in pct_pop is 0.3 or more
        if row['Year'] >= 2012 and abs(row['pct_pop'] - previous_pct_pop) >= 0.3:
            # Filter previous years
            previous_data = df[(df['Year'] < row['Year']) & (df['Location+Type'] == row['Location+Type'])]
            # Calculate average if row above is not empty
            if not previous_data.empty:
                return previous_data['Price'].mean()
        else:
            return row['Price']  # if pct_pop change was smaller than 0.3 or year is older than 2012, - use default price.
    else:
        return row['Price']   # if index 0 (first row) use value from first row of col: Price
    return None

# Apply the function to create the new_price column
df_sample['new_price'] = df_sample.apply(lambda row: calculate_new_price(row, df_sample), axis=1)

print(df_sample)
  Location+Type  Year  Price   pct_pop  new_price
0             A  2010      1       NaN   1.000000
1             A  2011      2  1.000000   2.000000
2             A  2012      1 -0.500000   1.500000
3             A  2013      3  2.000000   1.333333
4             B  2010      1 -0.666667   1.000000
5             B  2011      1  0.000000   1.000000
6             B  2012      1  0.000000   1.000000
7             B  2013      1  0.000000   1.000000
'


This code works but I am not understanding how I am getting KeyError: 562107 for my particular dataframe, any chance I could send it to you to see if you know how to debug it?

Why not, go ahead and share it via any cloud service

Thank you, appreciate it, do you have an email I could share the file with you?

just drop it on the sharedrive and update the question with the link, - more people would be able to help...
I am not a pro, - still learning also :)

I got it working now, but will drop a link

Dropped a link with your code that is modified for my data let me know if you can access it.

Why did you use abs(row['pct_pop'] - previous_pct_pop) >= 0.3 and not abs(row['pct_pop']) >= 0.3?

@Vitalizzare the question was "if the percentage Change is greater than 30 percent "

Here is a more concise way of doing it.
There is no loop. However, the apply method goes through each row.
import pandas as pd

sample = {
    "Location+Type": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Year": ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"],
    "Price": [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=sample)

# It is safer to sort by Location+Type and Year before calculating the pct_change
df_sample = df_sample.sort_values(by=['Location+Type', 'Year'])
df_sample['pct_pop'] = df_sample.groupby('Location+Type')['Price'].pct_change()

# Function to calculate the new price
def update_price(row, df):
    if row['Year'] >= '2012' and abs(row['pct_pop']) > 0.30:
        prev_prices = df[(df['Location+Type'] == row['Location+Type']) & (df['Year'] < row['Year'])]['Price']
        return prev_prices.mean()
    return row['Price']

# Apply the function to the dataframe
df_sample['New_Price'] = df_sample.apply(lambda row: update_price(row, df_sample), axis=1)

df_sample.head(8)

which gives

    Location+Type   Year    Price   pct_pop New_Price
0   A               2010    1       NaN     1.000000
1   A               2011    2       1.0     2.000000
2   A               2012    1       -0.5    1.500000
3   A               2013    3       2.0     1.333333
4   B               2010    1       NaN     1.000000
5   B               2011    1       0.0     1.000000
6   B               2012    1       0.0     1.000000
7   B               2013    1       0.0     1.000000


Could you follow the new update, I have a dataframe in a drive.

I tested your solution with the dataframe I have listed above it does not work. Simply try using your method and check the values.
